# I am trying to vlookup multiple values in one cell based on the a selection from another cell and output in next sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to vlookup multiple selection(comma seperated) in single cell and get the ouput in next sheet in single cell with single value (Either "Y" or "N") based on the input criteria (opt LCD vendor column in input table image) and functional usecase column (slection of multiple value ";" seperated) in input table image:

[image]

[image]

Output conditions:
I should get the output as "Y" only if both/all/multiple selected criteria (functional usecaeses) are "Y"
if one selection is "N" and the remaining are "Y", output should be "N"

Not sure it could be done in VBA / formula. could you please help on it.

As of now, Used this code for multi select functionality in functional usecase column & another 2 column

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
'MsgBox "called" + ActiveSheet.Name + "::" + Target.Address

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Input" Then
    If (Target.Column = 19 Or Target.Column = 6 Or Target.Column = 13) Then
    'If Target.Address = "O" Then
      If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
      Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
          If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
          Else
            If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
          Else:
            Target.Value = Oldvalue
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That just looks like you have copied someone's code and don't understand what it does.  Have you tried writing code yourself for your specific use case?  You mention VLOOKUP but the code you've copied has nothing to do with VLOOKUP.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rg = sh1.Range("B3", sh1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rgTbl = sh2.Range("A1", sh2.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rg
VL = "Y"
CL = rgTbl.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Column
x = Split(cell.Offset(0, 1), ", ")
    For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    VL = UCase(rgTbl.Find(x(i)).Offset(0, CL - 1))
    If VL = "N" Then Exit For
    Next
cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = VL
Next

End Sub
```

sh1 is the sheets where your "OPT LCD Vendor" reside.
So, change the sh1 according to your sheet name.

rg is the range of your "OPT LCD Vendor" header.
The code assumed that the data starts from cell B3 to the last rows which has value. rg values for example are : Outsystems, Any, Mendix, Unqork, etc.

sh2 is the sheet where your table has Y N.
So, change the sh2 according to your sheet name.

rgTbl is the range of the table in sh2.
The code assumed that the table starts from cell A1 to whatever last row in column F which has value. Change the range according to your need.

The process:
The code loop to each cell in rg,
get the value of the cell,
then find what column in rgTable this value exist, the CL variable.

The code split the value of the cell.offset(0,1) if the value has a comma separated.
For example, based on your image - the x variable will have two values : Life Origination and Accelerated Underwriting.

Then the code loop the value of x to get the VL is Y or N
Once it get the VL is N, it exit the loop, but it will continue if the value is not N. Finally the VL value (the result is Y or N) is put in column D of sh1 at the row of the looped cell, assuming that there is nothing in column D.

FYI, the value in column C of sh1 must always comma separated then one space.
 For example : Life Origination, Accelerated Underwriting ---> correct.
 Life Origination,Accelerated Underwriting ---> not correct.

This if I'm not mistaken to get what you mean.